# Are static methods always loaded into memory?

Tags: java, static, static-methods

Say that I have a Java project with some "Utils" classes, and that those classes have only `static` methods and members.

Once I run my application, are those methods and members automatically loaded into memory? Or that only happens once I call the class along the code?

**EDIT:** Some sample code to illustrate my question.

**RandomUtils.java**

```
public class RandomUtils {

    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Some other operations. Is my class already loaded here?

            int randomNumber = RandomUtils.randInt(1,10); // Or is it only loaded here?
        }
}
```

And what if that class have other static members and methods, and if it loads only once I call one of them, the other methods are loaded as well?

Comment: Downvoter, could you explain what's the problem?

Comment: For a general discussion see: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/when-class-loading-initialization-java-example.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static methods (and non-static methods, and static/member variables) are not loaded into memory directly: the declaring class is loaded into memory in its entirety, including all declared methods and fields. As such, there is no difference in the way that static/non-static methods/fields are loaded.

A class is only loaded by a class loader the first time it is referenced by other code. This forms the basis of the [Initialization on demand idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom).

Comment: So the only real difference is that I don't need to create an object for that, right?

Comment: You don't need to create an *instance* of that class, no.

Comment: I mean, both `static` and `non-static` will load the Class fully on the memory once called and instantiated, right?

Comment: You can't load part of a class. You have to load the whole class to use any of it.

Answer (score 2):

Your class is loaded when (among other conditions) its `static` method is called for the first time. See [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

Answer (score 1):

static methods loads only once when you call class.[image]

college="ITS" is an static variable

Comment: college is an static variable that loads only once when you call the class

Comment: How does it show that? What is `college` actually used for? Is there meant to be some code accompanying the diagram?

Comment: s1 and s2 are class objects.Using this objects we can directly access value of college variable.This same happens with static methods.

Answer (score 0):

it happens once you call the class.